# Adding delimiter for best_in_place gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In the normal form I have used this:

```
<td>
   <%= number_with_precision(approved_invoice.invoice_amount,
      :precision =>2,
      :delimiter => ",")
   %>
</td>
```

This adds the comma at the appropriate place. What if I have to use this delimiter for best_in_place gem:

```
<td class="tax-particulars-align">
   <%= best_in_place @invoice, :invoice_amount,
      :display_as => :get_invoice_amount_with_precision,
      :type => :input
   %>
</td>
```

How can I give the commas for the amount field in my edit page? Can someone help me in this?

Comment: Can anyone give me any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use number_with_precision in your model's get_invoice_amount_with_precision method. In order to make this accessible, you will need to include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper in your model:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper

  def get_invoice_amount_with_precision
    number_with_precision(invoice_amount, :precision => 2, :delimiter => ',')
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks I tried it and its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

As of best in place 1.0.3 you can use custom methods in your model in order to decide how a certain field has to be displayed. You can write something like this (in the view):

```
best_in_place @user, :description, :type => :textarea, :display_as => :my_formatting
```

And in the model:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper

  def my_formatting
    number_with_precision(description, :precision => 0, :delimiter => " ")
  end
end
```