# Adding delimiter for best_in_place gem while editing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, best-in-place

This is a follow up question to [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11933884/adding-delimiter-for-best-in-place-gem) thread.
But after i edit the value and save it, it goes back to a non-delimited number.
How can i make it keep its delimitation so even after i edit the field, it will keep its comma?

So on my best_in_place I have:

```
= best_in_place_if is_edit(@donation), @donation, :money_amount, display_as: :money_delimiter
```

In my model:

```
class Donation < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
  def money_delimiter
    number_with_delimiter(self.money_amount)
  end
end
```

Thanks guys for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a virtual attribute, since you have half of one already:

```
class Donation < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
  def money_delimiter
    number_with_delimiter(self.money_amount)
  end

  def money_delimiter=(value)
    self.money_amount = value && value.to_s.gsub(/[^\d\.]/,'').to_f
  end
end
```

Then just use that in best_in_place:

```
best_in_place_if is_edit(@donation), @donation, :money_delimiter
```

I think you'll have to use events to guarantee a format after someone edits the field. Use javascript to parse the content and ensure its value. Something like this:

```
$('.best_in_place[data-attribute=money_delimiter]').bind('ajax:success', function() {
  var content = $(this).html();
  // parse and check content
  $(this).html(content);
});
```

You may have to make that selector more specific.

Comment: It says that .to_f is undefined. am i supposed to include something else in there?

Comment: Doh. Forgot the second field in gsub: `gsub(/[^\d\.]/,'')`